# How to segment elements from an array of values (C/C++)

Tags: c

Good morning!
Given the following input example from a text file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnMlV.png

I have been handed the following task:

- Insert the values into an array
- Gather duplicate values into different TYPES of segments and count the number of values in each segment, as shown in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qepoa.png
- Form a 2-line Matrix where each column represents a different segment, the first line represents the type of segment for each individual segment, and the second line represents the number of values in that specific segment, as shown in the following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncNnC.png

I have no problem with the first and last parts of the task, however I do not know how to separate the values into different segments nor classify them. Sorry for the complicated explanation, but thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 1. C and C++ are different languages, only tag the one you are specifically asking about as the solutions will differ 2. Please show your attempt at coding this, and indicate specifically where you are stuck, otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: did they ask you to write it in C and C++? This doesn't sound like a task where you need both

Comment: My bad, the language I am supposed to use is C, not C++

Comment: take value, create a new segment and segment type for it and while next value same as value, include it in the current segment, else start a new segment, see if the type already exists otherwise create new one as well... and so on...? The picture is pretty self explanatory.